# Strange effect when translating world space UI Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

My canvas get strange effects when translated, looks like two canvas ontop och eachother and one lags behind the first. Like this

[image]

I attach the canvas like this to the controller (The Menu prefab has its canvas set to world space)

```
 currentMenuOwner = hand;
 currentMenu = Instantiate (MenuPrefab);
 currentMenu.transform.SetParent (currentMenuOwner.transform);
```

I then move it like this from Update

```
 currentMenu.transform.position = currentMenuOwner.transform.position;
 currentMenu.transform.rotation = currentMenuOwner.transform.rotation;
 currentMenu.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0.16f);
 currentMenu.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (90, 0, 0);
```

update: Added this code to the attach code above, didnt help

```
currentMenu.GetComponent<Canvas>().worldCamera = NVRPlayer.Instance.Head.GetComponentInChildren<Camera> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** move/translate `Canvas` unless the `Render Mode` is `World Space`. You can move the child UI components of the Canvas. If you want to translate your Canvas, change the **Render Mode** to **World Space** then put the main camera in the Canvas' `Event Camera` slot.

Comment: it is world space otherwise i wouldnt be able to take above screen shot would I?

Comment: @Anders you will always be able to take a screenshot of a canvas no matter the mode. since you've updated your post to show that this is a world mode, more info is still required for me to understand how your scene is setup. Are the two canvas child or parent of each other or are they separate from each other? Also temporary rename your variables such as canvas1 and canvas2. That will help determine how your scene is setup and how you are moving stuff since no one else can see your hierarchy from here.

Comment: the title says "translating world space UI Canvas". Anyway, i upgraded from Unity 5.3.4 to 5.3.5 and now its gone. edit: two canvas? Its one canvas

Comment: @Anders Missed the world space in the title and the image looked like two canvas to me. Congrats for finding the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is how it looked and that was the reason for my question.